# Strangeness using /usr/xpg4/bin/tr and /usr/bin/tr on Solaris 9

Tags: solaris, regex, sunos

I have a file looking like this,

```
"xxxxxx"
"yyyyyy"
"aaaaaa"
"cccccc"
"bbbbbb"
"eeeeee"
"oooooo"
"zzzzzz"
```

Wanting to replace each `\n` in this file I use:

```
tr '\n' ',' < INPUT > OUTPUT
```

Which works fine. The output is to be expected:

```
"xxxxxx","yyyyyy","aaaaaa","cccccc"....
```

**However**

I can't do any manipulation using `sed` or `awk` on this file, none what so ever (the result is always blank, like: `sed 's/,/hello/g'` displays nothing), in Linux using the GNU package this works fine, but with non GNU not. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Thanks in advance,

Anders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# ls
testfile.txt
# /usr/xpg4/bin/tr '\n' ',' < testfile.txt
"xxxxxx","yyyyyy","aaaaaa","cccccc","bbbbbb","eeeeee","oooooo","zzzzzz",,# 
# /usr/xpg4/bin/tr '\n' ',' < testfile.txt | sed 's/,/hello/g'
# ls -l /usr/xpg4/bin/sed
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root     bin        27460 Apr  7  2002 /usr/xpg4/bin/sed
# /usr/xpg4/bin/tr '\n' ',' < testfile.txt | /usr/xpg4/bin/sed 's/,/hello/g'
sed: Missing newline at end of file standard input.
"xxxxxx"hello"yyyyyy"hello"aaaaaa"hello"cccccc"hello"bbbbbb"hello"eeeeee"hello"oooooo"hello"zzzzzz"hellohello
# command -v sed
/usr/bin/sed
```

It seems sed is to blame, not tr ... . Using XPG4 sed does seem to fix the problem. As to why exactly, grrrrmmm... .

Edit: actually, when I add a newline to the output of the tr command, it does work with both sed editions, so I suppose /usr/bin/sed really needs a newline, and /usr/xpg4/bin/sed is a little more forgiving on the matter... .

Comment: Sweet, I forgot about xpg4 `sed`!